# Why doesn't PWM work on arduino in this code?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, pwm, pid

I am trying to control a dc motor speed with PWM. When I test it with simple program like spin in one direction with set PWM value it works. If PWM>70 the motor will start spinning and max is 255.

But when I try to do the same in code below it only spins if PWM value is 255. Can someone help me?

test.ino

```cpp
/*--------------------*/
// encoders
/*--------------------*/
//motor_encoder
int encoder0PinA = 3;
int encoder0PinB=2;
volatile int encoder0Count = 0;
volatile float angle0 = 0;
volatile float velocity0 = 0;
volatile float angle0_previous = 0;
volatile float angle0_post = 0;
//pendulum_encoder
int encoder1PinA = 20;
int encoder1PinB = 21;
volatile int encoder1Count = 0;
volatile float angle1 = 0;
volatile float velocity1 = 0;
volatile float angle1_previous = 0;
volatile float angle1_post = 0;
float error=0;
/*--------------------*/
// motor
/*--------------------*/
int enA = 10;
int in1 = 9;
int in2 = 8;
/*--------------------*/
// for Timer2
/*--------------------*/
volatile int tcnt2 = 131;
volatile int t = 0;

volatile float error_proportional = 0;
volatile float error_derivative = 0;
volatile float error_integral = 0;
float kp =50;
float kd = 0;
float ki = 0;
float u = 0;
float motor_input = 0;
int INPUT_MAX = 255;
int P=0;
int I=0;
int D=0;
int integral=0;
void setup()
{

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);

  /*--------------------*/
  // for encoder
  /*--------------------*/  
  // for encoder 0
  pinMode(encoder0PinA, INPUT); 
  pinMode(encoder0PinB, INPUT); 
  attachInterrupt(0, doEncoder0A, CHANGE);  
  attachInterrupt(1, doEncoder0B, CHANGE);  
  // for encoder 1
  pinMode(encoder1PinA, INPUT); 
  pinMode(encoder1PinB, INPUT); 
  attachInterrupt(2, doEncoder1A, CHANGE);  
  attachInterrupt(3, doEncoder1B, CHANGE);    

  /*--------------------*/
  // for Timer2
  /*--------------------*/
  // interrupts every 1 ms
  TIMSK2 &= ~(1<<TOIE2);
  TCCR2A &= ~((1<<WGM21) | (1<<WGM20));
  TCCR2B &= ~(1<<WGM22);
  ASSR &= ~(1<<AS2);
  TIMSK2 &= ~(1<<OCIE2A);
  TCCR2B |= (1<<CS22)  | (1<<CS20);
  TCCR2B &= ~(1<<CS21);
  TCNT2 = tcnt2;
  TIMSK2 |= (1<<TOIE2);

  Serial.begin (9600); // for debugging
}

void loop()
{

 error = angle1;

 if (abs(error) < 2){ 
 integral = integral + error; 
 }
 else {
 integral=0; 
 }
 P = error*kp;
 I = integral*ki; 
 D = (angle1_previous-angle1)*kd; 
  u = P + I + D;
  motor_input = 255/24 * u; 

  Serial.print("u: ");
  Serial.print( u);
  Serial.print(" ");
  motor_input = (int)motor_input;

  if (motor_input >= INPUT_MAX){
    motor_input = INPUT_MAX;
  }
  else if (motor_input <= -INPUT_MAX){
    motor_input = -INPUT_MAX;
  }

  Serial.print("error_proportional: ");
  Serial.print(error_proportional);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("error_derivative: ");
  Serial.print(error_derivative);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("error_integral: ");
  Serial.print(error_integral);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("motor_input: ");
  Serial.println(motor_input);
  setMotorSpeed(motor_input); 
}
```

measure_states.ino

```cpp
/*--------------------*/
// enkoder od motora
/*--------------------*/
void doEncoder0A(){  
  if (digitalRead(encoder0PinA) == HIGH) { 
    if (digitalRead(encoder0PinB) == LOW) {
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count - 1;
    }
  }
  else {                                     
    if (digitalRead(encoder0PinB) == HIGH) { 
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count - 1;
    }
  }
  angle0 = 0.000785*encoder0Count;  // radian  (2*pi/8000)
}

void doEncoder0B(){  // interrupt 1 function
  if (digitalRead(encoder0PinB) == HIGH) {   
    if (digitalRead(encoder0PinA) == HIGH) { 
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count - 1;
    }
  }
  else {                                   
    if (digitalRead(encoder0PinA) == LOW) { 
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder0Count = encoder0Count - 1;
    }
  }
  angle0 = 0.000785*encoder0Count;  
}

/*--------------------*/
// for encoder 1
/*--------------------*/
void doEncoder1A(){  
  if (digitalRead(encoder1PinA) == HIGH) {  
    if (digitalRead(encoder1PinB) == LOW) { 
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count - 1;
    }
  }
  else {                                     
    if (digitalRead(encoder1PinB) == HIGH) { 
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count - 1;
    }
  }
  angle1 = 0.000785*encoder1Count;  
}

void doEncoder1B(){  
  if (digitalRead(encoder1PinB) == HIGH) {  
    if (digitalRead(encoder1PinA) == HIGH) { 
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count - 1;
    }
  }
  else {                                   
    if (digitalRead(encoder1PinA) == LOW) { 
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count + 1;
    } 
    else {
      encoder1Count = encoder1Count - 1;
    }
  }
  angle1 = 0.000785*encoder1Count;  
}

ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) {  
  TCNT2 = tcnt2;  
  t++;

  // estimate velocity
  if (t == 1){
    angle0_previous = angle0;
    angle1_previous = angle1;
  }
  else if (t == 20){
    angle0_post = angle0;  
    angle1_post = angle1;
  }
  else if (t == 21){
    velocity0 = (angle0_post - angle0_previous)*50;  // rad/s
    velocity1 = (angle1_post - angle1_previous)*50;

    error_proportional = 3.1416 - angle1;
    error_derivative = 3.1416 - velocity1;
    error_integral = error_integral + error_proportional;

    t = 0;
  }
}
```

motor.ino

```cpp
void setMotorSpeed(int speed)
{
  if (speed < 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);

  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);

  }

  analogWrite(enA,abs(speed));

  angle1_previous=angle1;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I found that the code below for setting timer messes PWM but Im not sure why. Anyone have any idea?

```cpp
TIMSK2 &= ~(1<<TOIE2);
  TCCR2A &= ~((1<<WGM21) | (1<<WGM20));
  TCCR2B &= ~(1<<WGM22);
  ASSR &= ~(1<<AS2);
  TIMSK2 &= ~(1<<OCIE2A);
  TCCR2B |= (1<<CS22)  | (1<<CS20);
  TCCR2B &= ~(1<<CS21);
  TCNT2 = tcnt2;
  TIMSK2 |= (1<<TOIE2);
```

Comment: Arduino core uses built in timers to perform PWM - setting them manually using the AVR registers messes it up. [This](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency) may be helpful - see the part where it says which timer corresponds to which pins.

Comment: In loop(), after you set `P`, `I`, `D`, and `u`, it looks like you mean to calculate `motor_input` in float, but the calculation is will be partially done in int. The compiler will precalculate (int)255 / (int)24 as (int)10. At run time, that will be floated to 10.0 and multiplied by `u`. If you really meant the multiplier to be 10.625 (the result of a floating divide), at least one of the two constants, `255` and `24` needs a decimal point to indicate that. I see that in your initializers, too. ...

Comment: ... Use a decimal point, a trailing 'F' or 'D' (for 'float' or 'double') in your numerical constants that you expect to be treated by the compiler as double, float, or double, respectively (doubles and floats will be the same on an Arduino). I doubt this will solve your motor no-start issue, but it will affect your controller.

Comment: !!Ach!! I failed to notice this was an obsolete post. Well, maybe my comment will do someone, somewhere, somewhen, some good...  :(